# Is restarting a branch a good idea?

Tags: mercurial

In a software I develop I have a main stable branch (`default` or `prod`) from which I develop new ideas.

I believe that usual way to do that is to start a branch, work on it and either abandon it (leave it as it is, close it, delete it) or merge into the default one.

A lot of my development are small tests which I would be glad doing in a `dev` branch, which I would ultimately merge into `default`, then restart with new ideas in `dev`.

**Are there major drawbacks with such an approach?**

The main one I see is what to do in case of a "bad" idea which I would like to discard. I could leave the existing `dev` hanging, start a new `dev` branch  and end up with several `HEAD`s for one branch - which does not sound like a good idea (but objectively I dot know why).

In short: is restarting a branch, overall, a good idea and is having potentially multiple `HEAD`s because of that a true problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would describe your proposed course of action as having a non-linear `dev` branch, i.e., it may have unnamed heads that are never merged into the main line. (Repeatedly merging work from `dev` into `default` doesn't necessarily make it non-linear in this sense). Mercurial has no trouble managing configurations like this, so technically speaking it's not problematic.

But if you feel that this would make your history hard to navigate, you might want to use a richer set of branch names. A compromise solution would be to do all your experiments in `dev`, but use tags to distinguish and identify the different branch heads. I often do that when I put aside an idea (or abandon it for good).

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with having multiple heads at all. Besides you can close (thus in essence hide) old, abandoned heads, if you think they should vanish from plain sight.

On the contrary, I would start a separate head for *each* new idea or feature I code, so that I can follow different thoughts in parallel. It also allows to merge them into your main line separately.

Comment: Thanks. When you say *"I would start a separate head for each new idea or feature I code, "* -  you mean a separate head for one branch (say, for the branch `dev` I mentioned), right? Ending up with several HEADs for one branch? (I want to make sure you do not suggest to start a new branch per idea, as I noted in my question)

Comment: Personally I do not even bother creating a separate branch for development and any of the features I code there, having several heads on default branch. I only occasionally create separate branches for major releases and its subsequent bug-fix releases, in some projects not even that.